# Adding lines and geometric shapes on matplotlib candlestick chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I have made a candlestick currency chart on python using `matplotlib.finance`. Everything is working but I would like to add lines and shapes on the actual chart. When I was using normal type of chart in matplotlib. I would be doing:

```
plt.plot([xmin, xmax], [0.0005,0.0005], linewidth=3, color='purple')
```

To draw a horizontal line from `xmin` to `xmax` (to be defined) at the 0.0005 price level.But since I am using the method `candlestick2_ohlc` I don't really know how to proceed...

This is what I have:[image]

This is what I am looking to get:[image]

Also is it possible to draw and fill triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drawing segments**

```
plt.plot([xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax])
```

**Drawing triangles**

```
x = [x1, x2]
y = [y1, y2]
plt.fill(x,y)
```

**Drawing polygons**

```
x = [x1,...,xn]
y = [y1,...,yn]
plt.fill(x,y)
```

It's that easy!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to draw a horizontal line is to use

```
plt.axhline(y=1.066)
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know any way to draw segments and triangles?

Comment: Very generally, you can draw such shapes as shown in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html). A triangle would be a `RegularPolygon`.